# Is there a better way to break columns every 3rd row in Bootstrap CSS with PHP? Equal-width multi-row

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I found the following in the bootstrap documentation:

Create equal-width columns that span multiple rows by inserting a .w-100 where you want the columns to break to a new line every 3rd column.  - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#equal-width-multi-row

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Try `col-md-4` instead  of `col`. No need of `w-100`

Comment: Thanks @User863, this was much more efficient!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "<div class=\"row\">";

$rows = [];
$rows = ["apples", "oranges", "bananas", "pears", "grapes", "watermelons"];



foreach ($rows as $value) {

    echo "<div class=\"col-md-4\">" . $value . "</div>";

}

echo "</div>"; //End of row
```